# Is it OK to generate session secret(or any other secret keys) and store it in host server?

Tags: node.js, session, secret-key

I'm testing Google OAuth2.0 on node.js + express and using express-session for managing session, and I came across that I need **Secret Key** for my session manager.

So I did some research and found [a post](http://pmuellr.blogspot.kr/2014/09/keeping-secrets-secret.html), which has some nice suggestions. But it seems to require some workarounds, like setting secret key as environment variable or keeping it in configuration file.

- Using the former, I need to enter environment variables every time I redeploy sever.
- Using the latter exposes my secret key to SCM.

**So I decided to generate random string and store it in the host file system.** It seems to solve all the problems I introduced above, but I'm noob to web development so I'm not sure whether this is legit.

Is there any cons or exploit to this method?

Below is my `sessionSecret.js` file:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath = '/home/ubuntu/results.txt';

function readSecretKey() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function(err, key) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(key);
            }
        });
    });
}

function writeSecretKey(key) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.writeFile(filePath, key, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(key);
            }
        }); 
    });
}

function generateRandomString() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        crypto.randomBytes(48, function(err, buf) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(buf.toString('hex'));
            }
        })
    });
}

module.exports.getOrCreate = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        readSecretKey()
            .then(function(key) {
                console.log("Key exists: " + key);
                resolve(key);
            }, function() {
                console.log("Key does not exists. Generating...");
                return generateRandomString();
            })
            .then(function(key) {
                if (key) {
                    console.log("Key generated: " + key);
                    return writeSecretKey(key);
                }
            }).then(function(key) {
                if (key) {
                    resolve(key);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

Passing secrets in as an environment variable is just moving the problem outside the app. You have to have them somewhere anyway.

Passing them as an argument is less secure than a file, because any user on the server can `ps aux` and see them.

The only thing you did wrong in my opinion is overcomplicating it. I recommend dropping most of the code from the `sessionSecret.js` and instead of generating it on the fly, just get it from the config file. Shutdown the app if config file is not there.

Don't store the secrets in repository/SCM 
I put my secrets in a special folder in /etc/ of the server. If someone gets access to that, stealing sessions is the least they can do.

Comment: But if I migrate my server to other host(though it happens rarely), I need to create that config file again and it increases complexity and possibility of making mistakes. Do you suggest that this is a necessary process and should be tested before deploy?

Comment: All I can say is my infrastructure is created by ansible scripts and any server in use comes pre-loaded with a copy of secret.json that ops keep safe somewhere. (now that I said it I want to make sure I know where a backup is becasue they contain keys for encrypted db entries too :P)

Answer (score 2):

Storing the session in an environment variable is considered best practice.

See [12factor.net/config](https://12factor.net/config)